# 8086 ASM: Reading constants from input file in DosBox

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox, emu8086

I have declared constants above the program, like

```
cal          equ    16  
length       equ    1000
```

And my question is: can I declare constants in my `.txt` files like this:

```
cal,cal,cal
```

To read from the file I use

```
mov bx, ax       ;file handler
mov ah, 3fh      ;interrupt number
mov cx, length
mov dx, offset music
int 21h
```

and I have declared in data segment

```
db  tab length dup (0)
```

Everything works properly while reading, but we need to read constants and not the ASCII number of characters. For example, if I have:

```
cal
```

It reads :

```
tab[0]= ascii of c
tab[1]= ascii of a etc
```

but I need

```
tab[0]= 16
```

Is that possible in DosBox with ASM?
Sorry for my english and thank You in advance ;).

Comment: It will be your job to translate the string `cal` into the value. Just like in any other language. You will need to code something like `if (strcmp(token, "cal") == 0) tab[i] = cal;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "read constants."  You can certainly use the constants to check for specific values: `cmp cx, cal` which basically means `cmp cx, 16`.  But I don't see how "the ascii value of c" (which is 99) could be mapped to 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confusing a lot of things. The constants you defined above are translated from text strings via `EQU` to integer values at *assembly time*(when you assemble the program). The strings you are trying to read from your text file **are not** integer values - they are still just *text* (without any mapping to the integer values you want).

Reconstructing this mapping from the binary file would be highly complicated if even possible.

I doubt that this is even possible - unless by creating a separate dictionary *before assembling* - because the text->value relation between `cal` and `16` is used by the PreProcessor for text replacement before assembling and not even the assembler *knows* of it. Therefore it won't be present in the Debug-info(like a `.PDB`-file or so) also.

Even if the Debug-info would be included in the binary file or delivered with it, it would be quite complicated to reconstruct such a relationship from it.

---

So, the short answer is:
You have to create a *Dictionary* or some other mapping from `cal`(string) to `16`(int) by yourself to parse the `.txt` files and get your desired values.